# Duplicate entry for primary key?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, eclipse, swing

I'm trying to UPDATE the values of a Database on my JAVA code but when I try to do so, it tells me 'Duplicate entry (nameOfSomething) for primary key'; even if the PK doesn't exist, is giving me this error and I don't know why. All help is welcomed; if more code is needed, I'll gladly add it. Thanks in advance.

```
/**
SO THE NEW ERROR WOULD BE ON THE IF/ELSE STATEMENT, WHICH IS TRHOWING THE ELSE, THAT SAYS "DATA WAS NOT UPDATED".
*/

JButton btnUpdate = new JButton("Update");
        btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String petname = txtName.getText();
                String petphoto = txtPhoto.getText();
                String pettype = txtType.getText();
                String color = txtColor.getText();
                int gender = Integer.parseInt(txtGender.getText());
                int isSterilized = Integer.parseInt(txtSterilized.getText());
                //DATE
                String pedigree = txtPedigree.getText();
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                String date_entry = df.format(datePicker.getDate());
                //END
                String vaccine1 = txtVaccine1.getText();
                String vaccine2 = txtVaccine2.getText();
                String vaccine3 = txtVaccine3.getText();

                Connection conn = null;
                PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/refugio","root","2797");
                    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE PETS SET PETPHOTO=?, PETTYPE=?, COLOR=?,GENDER=?,ISSTERILIZED=?,PEDIGREE=?,DATE_ENTRY=?,"
                            + "VACCINE1=?,VACCINE2=?,VACCINE3=? WHERE PETNAME=?"); //NEW CHANGE HERE

                    pstmt.setString(1, petname);
                    pstmt.setString(2, petphoto);
                    pstmt.setString(3, pettype);
                    pstmt.setString(4, color);
                    pstmt.setInt(5, gender);
                    pstmt.setInt(6, isSterilized);
                    pstmt.setString(7, pedigree);
                    pstmt.setString(8, date_entry);
                    pstmt.setString(9, vaccine1);
                    pstmt.setString(10, vaccine2);
                    pstmt.setString(11, vaccine3);
                    int i = pstmt.executeUpdate();

                    if(i>0) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data was updated");
                    }else { //NEW ERROR WOULD BE HERE
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data was not updated");
                    }
                }catch(Exception ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });
        btnUpdate.setBounds(48, 737, 356, 51);
        contentPane.add(btnUpdate);




/**
DATABASE DESCRIPTION:
petName     varchar(15) NO  PRI     
petPhoto    varchar(50) YES         
petType     varchar(10) NO          
color       varchar(15) YES         
gender       tinyint(1) NO          
isSterilized tinyint(1) YES         
pedigree    varchar(15) YES         
date_entry  timestamp   NO          
vaccine1    varchar(15) YES         
vaccine2    varchar(15) YES         
vaccine3    varchar(15) YES     

JUST IN CASE PK IS PETNAME. 
*/
```

Comment: how does your table looks like?

Comment: You're executing an `UPDATE` statement **without a `WHERE` clause**, so the statement will attempt to update **all rows** with the same values. Seems you need to go back to your SQL guide and reread the chapter teaching you about the `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sql statement is missing the where clause thus its causing all your `pets` to be updated to all be of the same value and one of those values looks to be the primary key which violates the primary key constraint

Try changing your sql statement to be

`UPDATE PETS SET PETPHOTO=?, PETTYPE=?, COLOR=?,GENDER=?,ISSTERILIZED=?,PEDIGREE=?,DATE_ENTRY=?,VACCINE1=?,VACCINE2=?,VACCINE3=? WHERE PETNAME=?`

this is presuming the `PETNAME` is the primary key ? Otherwise some more work will have to be done to get the ID of the row you want to update

**Update**

With your recent update to your sql you have to adjust your prepared statement parameters. `PETNAME` was moved to the last position so that should be spot 11 and the others should be adjusted accordingly

```
pstmt.setString(11, petname);
pstmt.setString(1, petphoto);
pstmt.setString(2, pettype);
pstmt.setString(3, color);
pstmt.setInt(4, gender);
pstmt.setInt(5, isSterilized);
pstmt.setString(6, pedigree);
pstmt.setString(7, date_entry);
pstmt.setString(8, vaccine1);
pstmt.setString(9, vaccine2);
pstmt.setString(10, vaccine3);
```

If you changed your query a little differently you can used named parameters instead of positional then that way if you changed where that named parameter is, you wouldn't have to readjust the positions:

Example:

```
"UPDATE PETS SET PETPHOTO=:PETPHOTO, PETTYPE=:PETTYPE"

pstmt.setString("PETPHOTO", petphoto);
pstmt.setString("PETTYPE", pettype);
```

Etc...

Comment: So we made some progress; now it's telling me that the data was not updated, but at least is saying something, so now to see why it isn's being saved

Comment: Update your original post with your new sql and let us know what your primary key is and what the new message is.

Comment: Updated the post; if more code is needed, let me know

Comment: Updated my answer. Basically you have to readjust your positional parameters

Comment: Thank you for the extra tip; sure is easier to make them as named parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your update query is missing where condition. If you run an update script without where condition same data will be updated for all the rows.